# How to use store.filter / store.find with Ember-Data to implement infinite scrolling?

Tags: ember-data

This was originally posted on discuss.emberjs.com. See:
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-the-proper-use-of-store-filter-store-find-for-infinite-scrolling/3798/2

but that site seems to get worse and worse as far as quality of content these days so I'm hoping StackOverflow can rescue me.

**Intent:** Build a page in ember with ember-data implementing infinite scrolling.

**Background Knowledge:** Based on the emberjs.com api docs on ember-data, specifically the store.filter and store.find methods ( see: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter ) I should be able to set the model hook of a route to the promise of a store filter operation. The response of the promise should be a filtered record array which is a an array of items from the store filtered by a filter function which is suppose to be constantly updated whenever new items are pushed into the store.  By combining this with the store.find method which will push items into the store, the filteredRecordArray should automatically update with the new items thus updating the model and resulting in new items showing on the page.

For instance, assume we have a Questions Route, Controller and a model of type Question.

```
App.QuestionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (urlParams) {
        return this.get('store').filter('question', function (q) {
            return true;
        });
    }
});
```

Then we have a controller with some method that will call store.find, this could be triggered by some event/action whether it be detecting scroll events or the user explicitly clicking to load more, regardless this method would be called to load more questions.
Example:

```
App.QuestionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    ...
    loadMore: function (offset) {
        return this.get('store').find('question', { skip: currentOffset});
    }
    ...
});
```

And the template to render the items:

```
...
{{#each question in controller}}
   {{question.title}}
{{/each}}
...
```

Notice, that with this method we do **NOT** have to add a function to the store.find promise which explicitly calls `this.get('model').pushObjects(questions);` In fact, trying to do that once you have already returned a filter record array to the model does not work. Either we manage the content of the model manually, or we let ember-data do the work and I would very much like to let Ember-data do the work.
This is is a very clean API; however, it does not seem to work they way I've written it. Based on the documentation I cannot see anything wrong.

Using the Ember-Inspector tool from chrome I can see that the new questions from the second find call are loaded into the store under the 'question' type but the page does not refresh until I change routes and come back.  It seems like the is simply a problem with observers, which made me think that this would be a bug in Ember-Data, but I didn't want to jump to conclusions like that until I asked to see if I'm using Ember-Data as intended.

If someone doesn't know exactly what is wrong but knows how to use store.push/pushMany to recreate this scenario in a jsbin that would also help too. I'm just not familiar with how to use the lower level methods on the store.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just made this pattern work for myself, but in the "traditional" way, i.e. without using store.filter().

I managed the "loadMore" part in the router itself :

```
actions: {
    loadMore: function () {
        var model = this.controller.get('model'), route = this;
        if (!this.get('loading')) {
            this.set('loading', true);
            this.store.find('question', {offset: model.get('length')}).then(function (records) {
                model.addObjects(records);
                route.set('loading', false);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Since you already tried the traditional way (from what I see in your post on discuss), it seems that the key part is to use addObjects() instead of pushObjects() as you did.

For the records, here is the relevant part of my view to trigger the loadMore action:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
    var controller = this.get('controller');
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - ($(window).height()*2)) {
            controller.send('loadMore');
        }
    });
},
willDestroyElement: function() {
    $(window).off('scroll');
}
```

I am now looking to move the loading property to the controller so that I get a nice loader for the user.